# Bug onSelectRow in free-jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use **free-jqGrid v4.14.0.** I have a table, when I click on a row in this table, I execute a stored procedure and in another table I enter the result.
The problem is that when you first click on a row in the table, the data does not load into the second table, and when the second button is clicked, the data appears, and this problem occurs only once, the following clicks immediately load the data into the second table.
When you first click in the browser console, you can see that the url stored procedure is loading: **'@ Url.Action ("GetAccident")',**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jqg").jqGrid({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAccident")',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ['id_Accident', .......],
                    colModel: [
                    { name: 'id_Accident', index: 'id_Accident', autowidth: true, sortable: false },
                   .....................
                   .....................                                          
                    ],
                    guiStyle: "bootstrap",
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    pager: "#pager",
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],    
                    rowNum: 10, 
                    loadonce: false,   

                    onSelectRow:
                      function (idRow) {
                          celValue = $('#jqg').jqGrid('getCell', idRow, 'id_Accident');

                          jQuery("#jqg1").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Url.Action("GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident")?celValue=' + celValue, page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');             
                      }
                });



jQuery("#jqg1").jqGrid({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident")?celValue=' + 0,
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ['id_Accident', 'Name Organization'],
                    colModel: [
                { name: 'id_Accident', index: 'id_Accident', autowidth: true, stype: 'text', sortable: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', autowidth: true, sortable: true }
                    ],
                    guiStyle: "bootstrap",
                    pager: "#pager1",
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    rowNum: 10,                                                   
                });
```

Comment: You current code contains many small (and not so small) problems. Moreover, you don't described the interface of `GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident`. Which value could have `celValue` parameters (it's name is strange a little)? What ids (rowids) can be used in both grids? Is `Name` really the only column of the second grid (the `id_Accident` column should contains duplicates of the same value)? You wrote "...and when the second button is clicked...". What is "the second button"?

Comment: You wrote "you can see that the url stored procedure is loading: '@ Url.Action ("GetAccident")'", but you set `'@Url.Action("GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident")?celValue='` and not `GetAccident` inside of `onSelectRow`. I can continue... Could your review the text of your question and fix it? Could you describe more detailed **what you want to implement**? For example, you use `datatype: "json"` in the second grid initially. It means that you fill it with some data or at least make Ajax request to the server. If the grid should be empty initially then `datatype: "local"` would be better.

Comment: You use a lot of unneeded or wrong options/properties. For example, `{ name: 'id_Accident', index: 'id_Accident', autowidth: true, stype: 'text', sortable: true }` (see the second grid) can be reduced to `{ name: 'id_Accident' }`. The next problem: the variable `celValue` in not declared (`var` is missing).

Comment: Could you verify which request will be sent to the server on selection the row on the first grid (master)? You need just open Developer Tools of Chrome/IE and choose Network tab. You will see whether the request to `GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident` be sent or not.

Comment: The code from Advanced -> Master Detail or http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid is not good example. I can suggest you a better implementation, but I suggest to do this after the statement about the Bug in free jqGrid will be cleared.

Comment: first click on the table row   - GetAccident. second click on the table row - GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident. Third, fourth and so on  GetOrganizationCulpritByIdAccident until i reload the page

Comment: I suppose that the data from `Url.Action("GetAccident")` will be loaded because the page has **the first grid**. Could you clear Network traffic after loading the page and before first selection of the row of the first (master) grid? Then you should select the row of the first grid and verify which request will be sent to the server.

Comment: GetAccident  - request

Comment: Could you provide the demo, which reproduce the problem?

Comment: You can examine Network traffic of the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ed0yLkce/1/. I uses `datatype: "local"` in the second grid as initial option to prevent unneeded Ajax requests. You will see in Network tab of Developer Tools that the request to for example `https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json?celValue=test2` will be send it the second row is selected. I can't reproduce any bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for what you are doing. The problem was solved by adding   'idPrefix: "gm_"'

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. You can examine Network traffic of the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ed0yLkce/1/. I uses

```
datatype: "local"
```

in the second grid as initial option to prevent unneeded Ajax requests. I use additionally `idPrefix` with different values in both grids to be sure that one will have no conflicts with duplicates of ids. You will see in Network tab of Developer Tools that the request to for example `https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json?celValue=test2` will be send it the second row is selected.